# OpenCV fails on resizing

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm using Python with OpenCV, and I'm trying to open the camera. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: can't open camera by index 1
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: can't open camera by index 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "set_hand_hist.py", line 71, in <module>
    get_hand_hist()
  File "set_hand_hist.py", line 38, in get_hand_hist
    img = cv2.resize(img, (640, 480))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:3718: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'
```

I believe that this is the corresponding part of the Python code:

```
def store_images(g_id):
    total_pics = 1200
    hist = get_hand_hist()
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    if cam.read()[0]==False:
        cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    x, y, w, h = 300, 100, 300, 300

    create_folder("gestures/"+str(g_id))
    pic_no = 0
    flag_start_capturing = False
    frames = 0
    .... ... remaining code ... ...
```

I've tried looking on Google for a solution; however, nothing that I found yet works. I would really appreciate it if someone who is more experienced could take a look and try to help me out.

Thanks so much

Comment: If img = cv2.resize(img, (640, 480)) is failing it is because img is empty. Please provide further information: what is the code you're running and what the error message is. Where have you plugged your webcam? Is the device driver properly installed and functioning?

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to comment but I lack reputation. Seems like you can't open both cameras 1 and 0.

```
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: can't open camera by index 1
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: can't open camera by index 0
```

Please be sure a camera is connected to the system. If so, check that you have the appropriate Linux drivers installed for your camera.

And on line 38 of set_hand_hist.py, **img** variable is possibly an empty image. That's why you get an error on resize. You should investigate why **img** image is empty. Can't tell more without seeing the whole code.

**Edit**:You can try the code below to read images from the camera and show it. I believe the error is reading images from the camera. If the code below works, we should look elsewhere for the error.

```
import cv2

camera_index=1
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
if not cam.read()[0]:
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    camera_index=0

while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    cv2.imshow(f"image from camera {camera_index}", frame)
    if not ret:
        break
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k%256 == 27:
        # ESC pressed
        print("Escape hit, closing...")
        break

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hey, I think that both of those messages are coming up because the "open camera index 0" one is inside the conditional "if cam.read()[0]==False:," meaning that it only comes up provided that the first one fails.

Comment: @gallileo22 Edited the answer. Added a code to read from the camera. Please check the answer.